# powershell out file to text file single line?

Tags: powershell

```
$Date2,$Difference | Out-File $To2\Outputfile.txt -Append -width 200
```

Resulting my output in text files in 2 lines as below in, however i am expecting in one line start with another line

```
Friday, August 22, 2014 5:21:05 PM 00:00:07.4255524
Friday, August 22, 2014 5:22:15 PM 00:00:06.1931603
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is the ",". Use this `"$Date2,$Difference" | Out-File $To2\Outputfile.txt -Append -width 200`

In your example you are passing an array to the pipe with two elements `$Date2,$Difference` which will make the statement on the right fire once for each element. Creating a single string will add the output together in the file.